# sql get total and filtered count in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to tell what percentage of users for each team have more than 10 points. This currently requires two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as winners, team FROM users WHERE points > 10 GROUP BY team

SELECT COUNT(*) as total, team FROM users GROUP BY team
```

Can I do this in one so I get a result like this:

```
winners, total, team
5, 16, A
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) to check if `points` are more than 10 for a particular row, and count it accordingly (using `Sum()`).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN points > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS winners, 
       team 
FROM users 
GROUP BY team
```

---

In MySQL, we can shorten it further as [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function can simply cast results of conditional operators/functions to 0/1 (for false/true respectively):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
       SUM(points > 10) AS winners, 
       team 
FROM users 
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Are you missing an END keyword in your top query at the end of the SUM?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it just uses a case when instead of filtering the entire dataset in the where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total    
, SUM(case when points > 10 then 1 else 0 end) as winners
, team 
FROM users 
GROUP BY team
```

Can also do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total    
, COUNT(case when points > 10 then 1 else NULL end) as winners
, team 
FROM users 
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I wrote COUNT instead of SUM apologies.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You can use COUNT also, but you would have to write it like this instead: `COUNT(case when points > 10 then 1 else NULL end)`

Comment: Yes I know that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as winners, 
team, (select count(*) from users) as total FROM users 
WHERE points > 10 GROUP BY team
```

Or you can use case when

```
SELECT team, COUNT(*) as total , 
       count(CASE WHEN points > 10 THEN 1 end) AS winners  

FROM users 
GROUP BY team
```