# how to recover a single instance among several instances with group by in symfony doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, group-by, doctrine

here I have a booking table which includes doctors and patients ...
What I would like is to have the number of appointments per doctor. However in my table I have two doctors with several appointments. So I would like my doctrine request to return my list of my two doctors with their total number of appointments, but instead it will return all instances of my appointments.

**Entity Booking**
[image: booking table]

**My sql request in phpMyAdmin**
this is the result I would like:

[image: sql request]

**My Controller**

```
public function bookingbydocAction(Request $request){
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Utilisateur Inexistant');
    } else {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $medecin = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin')->findAll();
        $bookings = $em->getRepository('DoctixFrontBundle:Booking')->findBy(array('medecin' => $medecin));
  $nbbookhonored = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS nbr_booking_honored FROM 
  DoctixFrontBundle:Booking b WHERE b.statut like :approved GROUP BY b.medecin' )- 
   >setParameter('approved', 'approved')->getResult();

         $nbbookbydoc = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS nbr_booking_by_doc FROM 
   DoctixFrontBundle:Booking b GROUP BY b.medecin' )->getResult();
   $nbbookhonored = $nbbookhonored[0]['nbr_booking_honored'];
        $nbbookbydoc = $nbbookbydoc[0]['nbr_booking_by_doc'];

        return $this->render('DoctixAdminBundle:User:booking_medecin.html.twig', array(
            'bookings' => $bookings,
            'nbbookhonored' => $nbbookhonored,
            'nbbookbydoc' => $nbbookbydoc

        ));
    }
}
```

**My view Twig**

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">

                        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">

                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>NOM COMPLET</th>
                                <th>EMAIL</th>
                                <th>TÉLÉPHONE</th>
                                <th>NOMBRE RENDEZ-VOUS</th>
                                <th>HONORES</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                 <th>#</th>
                                <th>NOM COMPLET</th>
                                <th>EMAIL</th>
                                <th>TÉLÉPHONE</th>
                                <th>NOMBRE RENDEZ-VOUS</th>
                                <th>HONORES</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>

                            {% for booking in bookings %} 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ loop.index }}</td> 
                                    <td>{{ booking.medecin.user.prenom|capitalize }} {{ booking.medecin.user.nom|upper }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ booking.medecin.user.username }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ booking.medecin.user.numTel }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ nbbookbydoc }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ nbbookhonored }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                             {% endfor %}  
                            <div class="navigation">  </div>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

**The result of the view**
[image: view's result]

The problem is that it brings me in the view, all the occurrences of the two doctors who have an appointment, or I would like him to bring me just a single instance of each doctor with the total number of their respective appointments.

**The repository**

```
public function findByBooking(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->select('d.id, m.nom, m.prenom, m.username, m.numTel, COUNT(b.id) AS bookingsCount')
    ->join('d.bookings', 'b')
    ->join('d.user', 'm')
    ->groupBy('d.id');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are looping through the wrong array.

Comment: @MartinM.I loop on booking because that is what allows me to have the info (name, first name ...) on the doctor

Comment: You can easily achieve the desired result with a custom function in the doctor repo. Some pseudo code: `$this->createQueryBuilder('d')->select('d.id, d.name, COUNT(b.id) AS bookingsCount')->join('d.bookings', 'b')->groupBy('d.id')`. Maybe this points you in the right direction.

Comment: The custom function must be in doctor repo or booking repo ?

Comment: If you are listing doctors it should be in the doctor repo. It can be in any repo but it wouldn't make sense. For that you need to also add `->from()` to tell the builder manually which entity class you are selecting from.

Comment: ok, so and for the loop in my view ? I must remove it in my view ?

Comment: From the example I gave you you would have `$doctors = $doctorRepo()->getList()` in the controller, pass it to the view and: `{% for doctor in doctors %}` and simply show `{{ doctor.name }}` and `{{ doctor.bookingsCount }}`. I suggest you check some tutorials before posting question here. These things are in the official documentation.

Comment: I have checking some tutorials before. Soory for my inconvenience. And thanks again.

Comment: @MartinM.one question. 
if I would add a condition and display in a column the number of appointments whose status has been approved. how to add the where with access to the alias, please

Comment: Did Sean's answer work for you? I think it is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of best practice with Doctrine, you should be using Repositories:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine.html

You should change that 'like' to an '=' for optimization. You're not using any wildcard operators (%).

The main problem is your query. You should just join the tables together using the query builder, and then use the group by on all columns except the count. Just make sure all the columns you group by are also in your select.

**edit**
Keep in mind I don't know your entity structure, but something like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('booking');

return $qb->select('count(booking.id) as nbr_booking_by_doc, medecin.id, medecin.name')
    ->innerJoin('booking.medecin', 'medecin')
    ->innerJoin('booking.patient')
    ->where('booking.statut = :statut')
    ->groupBy('medecin.id')
    ->addGroupBy('medecin.name')
    ->setParameter('statut', 'approved')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

**edit 2**
Here's another question on SO that answers your question about getting both a total count and filtered count in a single query.

[sql get total and filtered count in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970788/sql-get-total-and-filtered-count-in-one-query)

Comment: I've added my repository. But I would add a condition and display in a column the number of appointments whose status has been approved. how to add the where with access to the alias in my view ?

Comment: See my example, it includes a where clause

Comment: You also need to add groupby's to all the other columns, except for the count

Comment: Yes i've seen your example, but in my repo,I have a first count that counts the number of appointments (all inclusive) but I need to add a second count that counts the number of appointments that has been approved (where statute =: approved), so I'm wondering how include this in a where and as create an alias to access via my twig view as for bookingsCount

Comment: Ah I see. That's not really a doctrine/symfony question then. That's an SQL issue. You'll need to join a sub-select in with the all inclusive counts and doctors id's

Comment: I've added a link to a previously answered question about what you're trying to do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution with my repo**

```
public function findByBooking(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->select('d.id, m.nom, m.prenom, m.username, m.numTel, COUNT(b.id) AS bookingsCount, SUM(CASE WHEN b.statut like :approved THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bookingshonored')
    ->join('d.bookings', 'b')
    ->join('d.user', 'm')
    ->setParameter('approved', 'approved')
    ->groupBy('d.id');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```